# how to modify compiler with cmake for cross-compiling

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, cross-compiling

I would like to build this library for an ARM architecture.

https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/

I am not sure how to go about changing the compiler and whatever is needed, since I need to build it for ARM.

Comment: What kind of machine are you building on?  Do you have a cross-compiler already?

Comment: Your question appears to be far too broad for StackOverflow. I suggest trying to compile it yourself and when you run into a _specific_ problem post a question and include the relevant details.

Comment: The issue is that I don't really know where to start from. I need to cross compile using arm-linux-gnueabi, and I don't know what to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad for a definitive answer, but here are some specific answers that may apply to your case:

The [Gentoo Embedded Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/embedded/handbook/) has lots of information on creating a cross compiler and toolchain.

The raspberry pi community is one of the largest for which cross compiling is a concern, there are several good discussions relating to many development platforms:

- [Windows](http://www.a2p.it/wordpress/tech-stuff/development/remote-debugging-raspberrypi/)
- [Linux / OS X](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-Cross-compiling-guide.html)